# How to clear TLS cache on iOS?

Tags: ios, caching, ssl, nsurlsession

Our server validates client cert. When user A login and get cert A, then switch to account B, we issue another cert B, which requests should use now.

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1727/_index.html,
we create another NSURLSession instance when user login account B, but system still use the TLS cache built with cert A.

How can I clear TLS cache?

Comment: Probably you persist you credentials. Try user NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone

Comment: @kostyl tried, no luck : (

Comment: Try to use NSURLSession with ephemeralSessionConfiguration with setURLCredentialStorage nil.

Comment: @kostyl still not working : [